# Jquery how to get ID and Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a UL and LI it working with function click but if get the title it not work.

Exemple:

```js
// it work but not get title
$("#list li").on('click', function() {

  var get_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var get_title = ///??? how to get title h2 selector
    //alert(get_id);
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/core.js"></script>
<ul id="list">

  <li id="myID">
    <h2>Title</h2> First One </li>
  <li id="myID2">
    <h2>Title 2</h2> Two </li>
  <li id="myID4">
    <h3>Title 3</h3> Tree </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: None of the elements have a `title` attribute? Do you mean the `text()` instead?

Comment: Also what output you want? `Title,Title 2,Title 3` or `First One,Two,Tree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the `h2` element then get the text using `text()` like :

```
var get_title = $(this).find('h2').text();
```

As @ParthShah suggested you could use a global class like `title_content` on your title elements, so you could target it easily using class selector :

```
  var get_title = $(this).find('.title_content').text();
```

```js
$("#list li").on('click', function() {
  var get_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var get_title = $(this).find('.title_content').text();

  console.log(get_id + ' - ' + get_title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li id="myID"><h2 class="title_content">Title</h2> First One </li>
  <li id="myID2"><h2 class="title_content">Title 2</h2> Two </li>
  <li id="myID4"><h3 class="title_content">Title 3</h3> Tree </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about the `h3`?

Comment: give class like "title_content" to your h2 and h3 tag and then fetch title by class name

Comment: Just use children()

Comment: The common classes are more efficient if it has a nested structure it will be a miss using `children()`...

Answer (score 1):

Use `:header`. No need to worry for any `h1,h2,h3...` tag.

```js
$("#list li").on('click', function() {
  var get_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var get_title = $(this).find(":header").text();
   console.log(get_title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">

  <li id="myID">
    <h2>Title</h2> First One </li>
  <li id="myID2">
    <h2>Title 2</h2> Two </li>
  <li id="myID4">
    <h3>Title 3</h3> Tree </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's find to query within your element.

```
var get_title = $(this).find("h2,h3").text() //add h4,h5 etc if you need to find those too.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/povu503s/

```
$(this).children().html();
```

Will take the first child and grab the HTML inside

Answer (score 0):

The title is a children of your targeted `li`. Use the `.children()` function to target that heading.

Hope this helps :>

```js
// it work but not get title
$("#list li").on('click',function(){
  var get_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var get_title = $(this).children().text();
  alert(get_title)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list" >
<li id="myID" > <h2>Title</h2> First One </li>
<li id="myID2" > <h2>Title 2</h2> Two </li>
<li id="myID4" > <h3>Title 3</h3> Tree </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

give class like "title_content" to your h2 and h3 tag and then fetch title by class name.

```
$("#list li").on('click', function() {
  var get_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var get_title = $(".title_content", this).text();
  console.log(get_id + ' - ' + get_title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer below Fiddle..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/bxaws99t/)

You can use any of below

```
 1. var get_title = $(this).find(':header').text();
 2. var get_title = $(this).children().text();
```